# Resizing multiple divs with mouse clicks

Tags: javascript, html, css

I took a look at this article and I wanted to try this same technique with more divs.

The above code works with 2 divs but not 4 divs. I tried to figure out why so I decided to try the following code.

```js
var handler = document.querySelector('.handler');
var wrapperWidth;
var wrapper = handler.closest('.wrapper');
var box = wrapper.querySelector('.box');
var isHandlerDragging = false;

document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  // If mousedown event is fired from .handler, toggle flag to true
  if (e.target === handler) {
    isHandlerDragging = true;
  }
});

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  // Don't do anything if dragging flag is false
  if (!isHandlerDragging) {
    return false;
  }

  // Get offset
  var containerOffsetLeft = wrapper.offsetLeft;

  // Get x-coordinate of pointer relative to container
  var pointerRelativeXpos = e.clientX - containerOffsetLeft;
  
  // Arbitrary minimum width set on box A, otherwise its inner content will collapse to width of 0
  var boxAminWidth = 60;

  // Resize box A
  // * 8px is the left/right spacing between .handler and its inner pseudo-element
  // * Set flex-grow to 0 to prevent it from growing
  
  wrapperWidth = wrapper.stlye.width;
  
  box.style.width = (Math.max(boxAminWidth, wrapperWidth - 8)) + 'px';
  box.style.flexGrow = 0;
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
  // Turn off dragging flag when user mouse is up
  isHandlerDragging = false;
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  /* Use flexbox */
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
  
  /* Use box-sizing so that element's outerwidth will match width property */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  /* Allow box to grow and shrink, and ensure they are all equally sized */
  flex: 1 1 1 1 auto;
}

.handler {
  width: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: ew-resize;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.handler::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 4px;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">A</div>
  <div class="handler"></div>
  <div class="box">B</div>
   <div class="handler"></div>
  <div class="box">C</div>
   <div class="handler"></div>
  <div class="box">D</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I wanted to have happen was the divs to be arrangeable.

You can take a look at the code here.

https://jsfiddle.net/paralaxwombat/1Lfqdb6x/

Comment: You have a typo at 'stlye'

Comment: Fixed. It still doesn't work :(

Comment: This code isn't even close to making divs rearrangeable. It will simply resize the first div with a class of "box". It won't resize the other divs because `querySelector` returns only the FIRST matching element. You need to find an article on drag and drop for rearranging divs, not for resizing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is what you want

```js
var wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
var box = null;
var isHandlerDragging = false;
var boxAminWidth = 60;
var new_width = 0, current_width = 0;

document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  // If mousedown event is fired from .handler, toggle flag to true
  if (e.target.classList.contains('handler')) {
    isHandlerDragging = true;
    box = e.target.previousElementSibling;
  }
  
});

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  // Don't do anything if dragging flag is false or 
  if (!isHandlerDragging) {
    return false;
  }
  
  // save the current box width
  current_width = box.style.width;
  
  // check the minimum width
 if ((new_width = e.clientX - box.offsetLeft - 8 ) >= boxAminWidth) {
  box.style.width = new_width + 'px';
 }
  
  // make sure the boxs dont go past the wrapper, aka: the overflow effect
  //if they do, we recover the last width of the current box to keep the boxs inside the wrapper.
  if(wrapper.lastElementChild.offsetLeft + wrapper.lastElementChild.offsetWidth > wrapper.offsetWidth) {
  box.style.width = current_width;
  }

});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
  // Turn off dragging flag when user mouse is up
  isHandlerDragging = false;
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #444;
  /* Use flexbox */
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 150%;
  
  /* Use box-sizing so that element's outerwidth will match width property */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  /* Allow box to grow and shrink, and ensure they are all equally sized */
  flex: 1 1 1 1 auto;
  
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;
   
   flex-grow: 0;
   flex-shrink: 0;
}

.handler {
  width: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: ew-resize;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.handler::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 4px;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box">A</div>
  <div class="handler"></div>
  <div class="box">B</div>
   <div class="handler"></div>
  <div class="box">C</div>
   <div class="handler"></div>
  <div class="box">D</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have some observations:

```
var handler = document.querySelector('.handler');
```

this line of code (unlike jQuery) selects **only the first** handler, not all of them, so this check `if (e.target === handler)` is valid only for the first handler, thus the mousemove won't work on all of them.
same thing goes for `var box = wrapper.querySelector('.box');`, you'll be always setting with to the first box.

This is the new javaScript code

```
var wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
var box = null;
var isHandlerDragging = false;
var boxAminWidth = 60;
var new_width = 0, current_width = 0;

document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  // If mousedown event is fired from .handler, toggle flag to true
  if (e.target.classList.contains('handler')) {
    isHandlerDragging = true;
    box = e.target.previousElementSibling;
  }

});

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  // Don't do anything if dragging flag is false or 
  if (!isHandlerDragging) {
    return false;
  }

  // save the current box width
    current_width = box.style.width;

  // check the minimum width
 if ((new_width = e.clientX - box.offsetLeft - 8 ) >= boxAminWidth) {
    box.style.width = new_width + 'px';
 }

  // make sure the boxs dont go past the wrapper, aka: the overflow effect
  //if they do, we recover the last width of the current box to keep the boxs inside the wrapper.
  if(wrapper.lastElementChild.offsetLeft + wrapper.lastElementChild.offsetWidth > wrapper.offsetWidth) {
  box.style.width = current_width;
  }

});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
  // Turn off dragging flag when user mouse is up
  isHandlerDragging = false;
});
```

In CSS, I made a small change in the box class:

```css
.box {
   /* ... */
   -moz-user-select: none;
   -khtml-user-select: none;
   -webkit-user-select: none;

   flex-grow: 0;
   flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is the answer to the question. Thanks for the tips as well.